# How to wire up MvxRecyclerView Item's actions to ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a MvxRecyclerView which has the following axml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_detail"
    app:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items" />
```

Correspodning ViewModel is defined like this:

```cs
public class ItemsViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Models.Item> _items;

    public ObservableCollection<Models.Item> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items);
        }
    }

    public MvxCommand CommandToBeInvokedFromItem
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(async () =>
            {
                await ...;
            });
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

My item_detail axml is defined like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:textSize="24dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name" />

  <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_black_24dp" 
    local:MvxBind="Click CommandToBeInvokedFromItem"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And Model.Item is defined like this:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

First TextView binds to Item's name property which works great.  But I want the ImageButton to bind to a Command on the ViewModel to which MvxRecylerView is bound rather than to a property of the Item.  Item is just a Model and not a ViewModel. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the command to be called on the click of an item in the `MvxRecycler` (i.e. the entire cell), the binding is relatively simple. Just change the value of `MvxBind` on the `MvxRecyclerView` from `ItemsSource Items` to `ItemsSource Items; ItemClick CommandToBeInvokedFromItem`. `CommandToBeInvokedFromItem` would then need to be modified to accept `Item` as a type parameter, which would look like this:

```
public MvxCommand<Models.Item> CommandToBeInvokedFromItem
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand<Models.Item>(async () =>
        {
            await ...;
        });
    }
}
```

If the command needs to be raised specifically by clicking on the `ImageButton`, then the easiest method would be to move `CommandToBeInvokedFromItem` to `Item`, and to have Item inherit `MvxViewModel`, or at least implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Luke, thanks but it is the second behaviour I desire.  I want to wire up a command to a click on the ImageButton that is located within the MvxRecyclerView "cell".  And yes, I was wondering If I could do that without having Item to inherit from MvxViewModel.

Comment: It should work fine without inheriting `MvxViewModel`. Just move `CommandToBeInvokedFromItem` to `Item`.

Answer (score 0):

Hand the command over to the `Item` when you create it in your`ItemsViewModel`.

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public MvxCommand CommandToBeInvokedFromItem {get;}

    public Item(MvxCommand clickCommand)
    {
        CommandToBeInvokedFromItem = clickCommand;
    }
}
```